# Как настроить работу skype через usergate 5?

Tags: usergate, proxy, skype

Как настроить работу skype через usergate 5?

Comment: Устанавливается без проблем, у меня на 5 машинах стоит через usergate5, одна проблема - долго добавляется новый контакт, а установка без проблем.

Comment: Да и я установил без проблем. У меня skype не пашет на машине, которая подключается к прокси

Answer (score 1):

На всех 5 машинах стоит через прокси, работает без проблем, никаких дополнительных настроек ни в Скайпе ни в пркси не делал.

Comment: если в прокси запрещен выход на данный адрес - то настройка скайпа на работу через прокси не поможет. Аналогично это касается всяких асек, мру-агентов и дрю сервисов.

Answer (score 0):

выставить разрешения на пользование скайпом в прокси-сервере (возможно как проброс портов или как разрешение на доступ по имени сайта...)